# Calculate distance between user position and geoJSON polygon leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, geojson

I need to calculate the distance between userposition and a and couple different geoJSON polygon in leaflet. I'm able to get the user position and the coordinates:

```
myPosition.getLatLng();
```

Now I need to get the polygons position and coordinates. Each feature look something like this:

```
{
      "type": "Feature",
      "properties": {
        "name": "name",
        "desc": "desc",
        "logo": "logotype.png",
        "distance": 0  
      },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Polygon",
        "coordinates": [
          [
            [
              13.135399818420408,
              47.109640413300816
            ],
            [
              13.13541054725647,
              47.109574695079196
            ],
            [
              13.135678768157959,
              47.10958199710783
            ],
            [
              13.135678768157959,
              47.109676923388875
            ],
            [
              13.135399818420408,
              47.109640413300816
            ]
          ]
        ]
      }
    }
```

And then I want to use the coordinates to calculate the distance in my function and return the value to another function that is printing the distance in a popup. How can I do this?

```
function onEachFeature(feature, layer) {


            layer.bindPopup("<h3>" + feature.properties.name + "</h3><br>" + "<p>" + feature.properties.desc + "</p><br>" + "<img src='" + feature.properties.logo + "'><br>" + "<p> Avstånd: " + feature.properties.distance + " m</p>")

            layer.bindPopup
        }

 function calculateDistance() {

    }
```

Comment: What distance are you looking for - your polygon has 4 points you could measure from, or is it something like the center or the nearest point on the circumference you want?

Comment: See if it's inside with https://turfjs.org/docs/#booleanPointInPolygon , and if not then https://turfjs.org/docs/#pointToLineDistance to each ring of the polygon.